# Docker & Angular - Can not connect to backend container from a angular based frontend container

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two containers: backend based on JavaEE and frontend based on Angular. Frontend will make some Http Requests to retrieve the data in backend. Here is an example of my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    backend:
        image: backend
        container_name: backend
        build: ./backend
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
    frontend:
        image: frontend
        container_name: frontend
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
            - "8085:80"
        environment:
            - REST_API_URL=http://backend:8080/vehicles
```

The environment `REST_API_URL` will be used in frontend with the HttpClient to send request to backend to get the data. I would like to use the backend container's name here but it did not work, it could not connect to backend, while if I change this to `http://localhost:8080/vehicles` then it worked. However if I go inside the frontend container and make a curl request to the address `http://backend:8080/vehicles` then I got the data, so confused for me.

My question here is why the angular HttpClient's call `this.http.get<Vehicle[]>(this.REST_API_URL)` can serve in my case only `http://localhost:8080/vehicles` but not `http://backend:8080/vehicles`???.

Here is also **Dockerfile** of my frontend:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

RUN apk add --update curl
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY /dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./entryPoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x entryPoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/entryPoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and the **nginx.conf**:

```
events{}
http {    
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;    
    server {        
        listen 80;
            server_name localhost;
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;        
        location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you need to add a docker network if you want to access `http://backend:8080`

```
version: '3'
services:
    backend:
        image: backend
        container_name: backend
        build: ./backend
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        networks:
            - mynetwork
    frontend:
        image: frontend
        container_name: frontend
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
            - "8085:80"
        environment:
            - REST_API_URL=http://backend:8080/vehicles
        networks:
            - mynetwork

networks:
    mynetwork:
```

If you want to access using `http://localhost:80`, you have to use the same `lo` inteface for both dockers:

```
version: '3'
services:
    backend:
        image: backend
        container_name: backend
        build: ./backend
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        network_mode: host

    frontend:
        image: frontend
        container_name: frontend
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
            - "8085:80"
        environment:
            - REST_API_URL=http://backend:8080/vehicles
        network_mode: host
```

Third possibility is use `http://host.docker.internal:8080` from your frontend to access backend. Please, verify first 8080 is not being used in your host. It's recommended to map 8086:8080 for example (and therefore use host.docker.internal:8086 or whatever), if you're not using docker networks.

Comment: Hi Alexjandro, Thank you for your suggest, I tried your solution but it also did not work

Comment: Are you using localhost or backend:8080 connection?

Comment: I tried with backend:8080. The localhost worked well already

Answer (score 0):

If you connect from your local machine u can use localhost, but if u connect from docker u have to use container name.
Then u have to connect to angulsr werver with localhost, but the angular api call should be backend:8080

Comment: I just copied from my post above : "My question here is why the angular HttpClient's call this.http.get<Vehicle[]>(this.REST_API_URL) can serve in my case only http://localhost:8080/vehicles but not http://backend:8080/vehicles???."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `links` to link the container together.

```
version: '3'
services:
    backend:
        image: backend
        container_name: backend
        build: ./backend
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
    frontend:
        image: frontend
        container_name: frontend
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
            - "8085:80"
        links: 
            - "backend"
        environment:
            - REST_API_URL=http://backend:8080/vehicles
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I did find a solution for the problem. I have to configure my nginx server to allow the backend's call using its service name pass through. So the nginx config should look like:

```
events{}
http {    
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;    
    server {        
        listen 80;
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;        
        location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }

        location /api/ {
                    proxy_pass ${REST_API_URL};
            }
        }
}
```

Here is meant that all the calls with the `/api` path will be forward to the backend.
And in angular code I just need to call the path instead of the whole backend URL, something like: `this.http.get<Vehicle[]>('/api/vehicles')`